# Change random text between strings with sed

Tags: sed

Example

```
text1"text2" text3"" text4 text5"text6"
or
text1"text2" text3"randomtext" text4 text5"text6"
```

should become in both cases

```
text1"text2" text3"foo" text4 text5"text6"
```

I want to insert something between the double quotes from text3.
The texts in other double quotes should not get touched.
Content between text3 double quotes can be empty or filled with random text that should get completely replaced then.

In case it's empty I would use

> sed -i 's/text3""/text3"foo"/g' file

But how should the code look like if string1 has random text between double quotes?
And can I use one command for both cases?

Tried

```
sed -i 's/(text3").*(" text4)/\1foo\2/g' file
```

but nothing happened :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([^"]*")[^"]*/\1foo/' input_file
sometext string1"foo" string2 sometext
or
sometext string1"foo" string2 sometext
```

Comment: Ok sry my fault.
To be clearer... The double quotes are not the only occurrences in that line.
sometext"sometext" string1"randomtext" string2 sometext"sometext"
Only the randomtext between these quotes should get replaced :)

Comment: @diggidre Please update your question to reflect this. Also, what can be used to identify `randomtext`? Is it the last occurrence of double quotes?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is more understandable what Im searching for.
No it is not the last occurrence of double quotes.
Only thing that is always the same is text3"" text4 or text3"randomtext" text4.

Comment: @diggidre If `text3` will always be the same, then does this work? `sed -E 's/(text3")[^"]*/\1foo/' input_file`

Comment: sed -E 's/(text3")[^"]*/\1foo/' input_file does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ERE for `()` to act as metacharacters.

```bash
$ sed -E 's/(text3").*(" text4)/\1foo\2/g' ip.txt
text1"text2" text3"foo" text4 text5"text6"
text1"text2" text3"foo" text4 text5"text6"
```

I'd recommend using `[^"]*` instead of `.*` to match only till the very next `"` character. Also, `g` flag isn't needed if there's only one match.

```bash
$ sed -E 's/(text3")[^"]*(" text4)/\1foo\2/' ip.txt
text1"text2" text3"foo" text4 text5"text6"
text1"text2" text3"foo" text4 text5"text6"
```

Comment: that worked for me.
also solution from Hateless comment above is working.
which to preferre?
sed -E 's/(text3")[^"]*(" text4)/\1foo\2/' ip.txt
or
sed -E 's/(text3")[^"]*/\1foo/' input_file

Comment: if you don't need `text4` to validate the match, you can use the shorter solution

Comment: if for some reason text4 changes position in some line then this would bring sed to avoid proceeding.
I think the shorter solution is better in this case. also because of text 3 remains static it garantees sed to act as its supposed to.